# Making a string by accessing dictionary values

Tags: python, string, dictionary

**years, months, days, hours, minutes** these values accessed from a dict. now I want to create a string like **years = 12 months= 1** if there is only years and months. Consider a case only minutes and second. then the string should be **minutes=1 seconds= 1** . how can I do this in an effective way??
The sample data may look like this

I tried to do something like this. But not working

```
    years, months, days, hours, minutes = self.initial_data["months"], \
                                            self.initial_data["years"], \
                                            self.initial_data["days"], \
                                            self.initial_data["hours"], \
                                            self.initial_data["minutes"], 
    duration = if years: "years= {}".format(years) + \
            if months "months={}".format(months) +\  
            and so on
```

So the string change by if there is value or not

Comment: Do you have a sample of the data?

Comment: The correct expression is `value if condition else othervalue`. For example  `("years={}".format(years) if years else "") + ...` You also have some other typographical errors in there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apart from bad syntax (you cannot use `if` in such a way), you're making this more complicated than it needs to be. Just create an ordered map and loop through it to extract existing fields from `self.initial_data`:

```
fields = ["years", "months", "days", "hours", "minutes", "seconds"]  # ordered list
data = self.initial_data  # a shorthand for readability sake
duration = " ".join("{}={}".format(f, data[f]) for f in fields if f in data)
```

You can add an additional `data[f]` check in the duration list build up if you want to ignore fields whose values evaluate to `False` (e.g. `0`, `None` etc.).